# How to apply outline button on ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 and using icons for buttons from https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/ionicons/.

I 'm going to use  but it shows only black filled image(iso-photos), not outline button with empty inner background(ios-photos-outline).

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ios-photos-outline` . If you do a search for photos it is the middle option.

You can default to this icon for all platforms by using the name attribute.

```
<button ion-button outline icon-left>
   <ion-icon name="ios-photos-outline"></ion-icon>
   Outline button
</button>
```